# SD card is damaged, even after I format and get new sd card, I'm still seeing the same error, Please help!

Tags: external-sd, sd-card

Hi I've found my 8 GB SD card damaged this morning. And I was able to access it on my computer and I collected the files on it, then FORMATTED it. However, when I put it back in my phone I'm still getting the same error : Damaged SD card.

So I've bought a brand new 2 GB SD card and I'm still receiving the same error: SD card Damaged. I'm using TECNO M3 , android 4.2.2
Please I need help fixing this problem.

PS: This problem has started when I put wi-fi on this morning, and the apps started updating automatically. And suddenly majority of my apps were removed on their own.BTW, I've check different threads here but it seems nobody is having the same problem as mine. I appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Comment: Try formatting the SD card on your phone instead of the PC. If it still shows the message, then your SD card might be broken.

Comment: The SD card was ok when you accessed it with your computer. Could it be some malware on your smartphone instead?

Comment: `And suddenly majority of my apps were removed on their own.` Is your device Rooted? @ott : I'm kinda skeptical about Malware doing so without Root access. To install/remove Apk's requires very higher privileges which certainly a malware (alike other apps if device not rooted) shouldn't be able to do. But may be a Vulnerability could've been exploited here or else, I could be wrong all along. Care to enlighten here. @Pearl : I agree with @gianttree, try formatting the card only in Smartphone from `Settings > Storage > Format External Storage`

Comment: I've tried formatting the SD card on my phone but I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: And I've tried using a new SD card and same problem happened, btw my phone is rooted. I'm thinking it could be a malware the way I'm seeing thing going. Anyways until the moment I didn't manage to fix it. Do you have other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Could be multiple things. With the "first card", you might have formatted it using a file system not supported by the device (e.g. NTFS). The second card *might* be broken/corrupt, though I think that unlikely. If a third card (maybe you can find one to try from another device?) doesn't work either, I'd rather consider the problem is with the device's card slot (e.g. contact issues).